# what is the difference between the two probabilities.

Tags: probability

When flipping a coin 4 times, what is the probability of getting 3H and 1 T, I know the answer is $\frac{4}{16}$ since we have 16 possible outcomes, 4 of them will come 3H and 1 T.

What I don't understand is why the following solution is logically wrong:

$P(3H, 4 flips) = \binom{4}{3}*(0.5)^3(0.5) = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(1T, 4 flips) = \binom{4}{1}*(0.5)(0.5)^3 = \frac{1}{4}$

Thus $P(3H,1T, 4 flips)  =\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{16}$

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)*P(B)$ is only true when $A$ and $B$ are [independent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks for your reply. can you clarify how P(A∩B) is dependent in that example? I thought P(3H out of 4 flips) and P(1T out of 4 flips) are independent.

Comment: If you have exactly 3H out of 4 flips, then the other flip is automatically 1T, and vice versa. So if you have 3H, the probability of having 1T is 100%, not 1/4.

Comment: oooh, now I see. Thanks a lot, that make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ is only valid for [independent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). In this case having exactly 3 heads in 4 flips automatically means you have exactly 1 tail, and vice versa, so these events are not independent at all but actually the same event.
Therefore $P(3H|1T)=P(1T|3H)=1$, i.e. if you have one you are certain to have the other. This means that $P(3H\cap 1T)=P(3H|1T)P(1T)=1\cdot\frac14=\frac14$.
If $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then by definition we have $P(A|B)=P(A)$, which gives $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)\cdot P(B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$